# Firebase realtime database events don't trigger in ios

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

I have a react app deployed to a server and it uses Firebase Realtime database. It is a multi-person game where each user goes to the website and it brings up a screen. One player at a time does something and it updates the realtime database properly and then it should trigger the next players turn on their browser automatically.  It seems to work well on Android and browsers in Windows. But as soon as I add a player on an iPhone(Safari) that player never gets any of the events coming from the Realtime database. So player 1 finishes their turn and it SHOULD trigger player 2's screen to change, but on IOS that never happens. I can see the proper data gets changed in the database, and as mentioned it works well on Android/Windows devices.  I tried Chrome on the iPhone and that seems to works sometimes, but not always.  Is there something I need to do in the app to fix this or is this a setting on the iPhone of some sort?

Some sample code was requested. This is the specific code that sets up the "listen" on the particular realtime database fields.

```
 this.listenGameDataFunction = onValue(this.gameDataRef,  (snapshot) => {
             // console.log("GAME DATA HAS CHANGED");
                const data = snapshot.val();
                // console.log("data="+data);
                this.gameDataChangedFunc(snapshot); // This is a function passed in to here
            });
```

Comment: Can you attach some example code?

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" and [Build a minimal, complete, reproducible example](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example)